# Accordion not working in Highcharts subtitle

Tags: highcharts

I have sometimes very long subtitles in my charts. Ideally I want to expand/collapse part of the subtitle.
If I use ang-accordion outside of the highcharts subtitle, it works correctly
https://github.com/sherwaniusman/angular-accordion

If I try to use it in the subtitle however (in highcharts.net) it doesn't show me text1, nor is anything clickable.

```
var subtitle = string.Format("<ang-accordion><collapsible-item item-title='{0}'><div>{1}</div></collapsible-item></ang-accordion>",text1, text2);
subtitle = new Subtitle { UseHTML = true,Text = subtitle, Align = HorizontalAligns.Left },
```

Is it feasible to use expand/collapse functionality in the subtitle?

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation it does not look like angular tags are supported. Taken from [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting#html):

> Texts and labels in Highcharts are given in HTML, but as the HTML is
>   parsed and rendered in SVG, only a subset is supported. The following
>   tags are supported: b, strong, i, em, br/, span. Spans can
>   be styled with a style attribute, but only text-related CSS that is
>   shared with SVG is handled.